# working on coroutine in python.How to link two coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine

I am running two coroutine functions bu tnot getting the desired output. Any help is appreciated. Below is the code.

```
def coroutine_decorator(coroutine_func):
    def wrapper(*x,**y):
        c = coroutine_func(*x,**y)
        next(c)
        return c
    return wrapper


@coroutine_decorator
def linear_equation(a, b):
    x=yield
    c=a*(x**2)+b
    print("Expression, {}*x^2 + {}, with x being {} equals {}".format(a,b,x,c))


@coroutine_decorator
def numberParser():
    y=yield
    equation1 = linear_equation(3, 4)
    equation2 = linear_equation(2, -1)
    equation1.send(y)
    equation2.send(y)




def main(x):
    n = numberParser()
    n.send(x)
    n.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main(6)
```

[attaching image for expected output, my current output and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HooRL.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Your code :

```
def numberParser():
    y=yield
    equation1 = linear_equation(3, 4)
    equation2 = linear_equation(2, -1)
    equation1.send(y)
    equation2.send(y)
```

change to following code

```
def numberParser():
   while True: 
        y=yield
        equation1 = linear_equation(3, 4)
        equation2 = linear_equation(2, -1)
        equation1.send(y)
        equation2.send(y)
```

You are getting error as yield value gets 'None' as absence of while